# SQL Server - Incorrect syntax near )

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please review this code?  I got this error and I'm not sure what's causing it:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
select * 
from
    (select distinct 
         sar90.code, sar90.state, sar90.county, 
         sabet.code, sabet.state, sabet.county 
     from
         [dbo].[sarshomari_90] as sar90, 
         [dbo].[Fixed] as sabet 
     where 
         sar90.county = sabet.county 
         and sar90.state = sabet.state 
         and sar90.state = N'kerman')
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I think you should try it by yourself for at least 10 min,  i call it  EARLY ERRORS of sql

Comment: How do you know, I did not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to alias your subquery. However, you do not need to use a subquery for this. You can use `SELECT DISTINCT` directly. Also, please [avoid using old-style `JOIN` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and use an explicit `JOIN` declaration instead.

However, if you wish to use subquery, your column must have unique names. Do this by adding unique aliases.

```
select *
from(
    select distinct
        sar90.code as code1, 
        sar90.state as state1,
        sar90.county as country1,
        sabet.code as code2,
        sabet.state as state2,
        sabet.county as country2
    from [dbo].[sarshomari_90] as sar90
    inner join [dbo].[Fixed] as sabet 
        on sar90.county = sabet.county 
        and sar90.state = sabet.state 
    where
        sar90.state = N'kerman'
)t
```

Comment: Yes I know, but it was part of a bigger query, I tried to use smaller part of my query. Plus, alias won't work, it gives another error.

Comment: @yousefyegane you need to post the entire code to help you

Comment: You should use unique aliases for each of your column in the subquery. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Add alias to subquery and alias to column to avoid ambiguous names.

```
select *
from
(select distinct
    [code1]   = sar90.code, 
    [state1]  = sar90.state,
    [county1] = sar90.county,
    [code2]   = sabet.code,
    [state2]  = sabet.state,
    [county2] = sabet.county
from [dbo].[sarshomari_90] as sar90, [dbo].[Fixed] as sabet
where sar90.county=sabet.county
      and sar90.state= sabet.state
      and sar90.state=N'kerman') AS tab
```

Comment: First I had AS, and it gives this error:
The column 'state' was specified multiple times for 'fin'.